# select strings with duplicate characters in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq

How can I use a linq query in C# to find the string that both contains "B" and "BZ"? To find the strings that only have "B" I use:

```
var query = from c in mapping
             where c.code.Contains("B") 
             select c;'
```

But if I say `where c.code.Contains("B") && where c.code.Contains("BZ")`obviously I got only the strings that have BZ because the first constrain will be satisfied in the second constraint. But what I need is to get the strings thast both have "B" and "BZ". (actually my words should have two Bs).

Comment: Does the order matter? That is, should `"...BZ...B..."` also match or only `"...B...BZ..."`?

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest to use regex, like:

```
    where Regex.Match(c, ".*(B.*BZ)|(BZ.*B).*").Success
```

Sample:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        var mapping = new[]
        {
            "BBZ",
            "B",
            "ABBA",
            "BZBZ",
            "BZAB",
            "BBZ",
            "ZBBAZ"
        };

        // the code
        var query = from c in mapping
                    where Regex.Match(c, ".*(B.*BZ)|(BZ.*B).*").Success
                    select c;

        Console.WriteLine("Matched:");
        foreach (string s in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Matched:
BBZ
BZBZ
BZAB
BBZ
```

Comment: This kinda work. But how about these senarios where I have "OCBZS" and "OCBZSB" and among them I want to select "OCBZSB"? what should I do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

> actually my words should have two Bs

(If you want it in Linq)

```
   var query = mapping.code.Where(s => s.Count(f=>f=='B')==2);
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution without relying on regex

```
            var x = from s in mapping
                let index1 = s.IndexOf("BZ") // find any 'BZ' in the string
                where index1 > -1 // ensure that a 'BZ' was found else the following queries will throw
                let index2 = s.IndexOf('B', 0, index1) // find the first B in the string
                let index3 = s.IndexOf('B', index1 + 1) // find a second B in the string
                where index2 > -1 || index3 > -1
                select s;
```

The trick is to first find the BZ, followed by finding a B either before or after the found BZ. The IndexOf operator is perfect for this since it allows us to select a starting position (after the found BZ) and a count (right before the found BZ).

Comment: This solution is using linq

Answer (score 1):

If it's only a matter of `B` and `BZ` in the string then you can check how many times `B` occurs in the string. So if you check for `BZ` and check that `B` occurs at least 2 times then you will get the strings you want

```
var query = from c in mapping
    where c.code.Contains("B") &&  // not really necessary but I keep it to make it explicit what we are looking for.
          c.code.Contains("BZ") && 
          c.code.Count(l => l == 'B') >= 2
    select c;
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much. The only small issue is that we have to choose another parameter instead of c for c => c == 'B'.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I usually go for letters standing for types in this case "c" for "char". But I've just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You should only have one where clause. Your second where is messing it up.

```
where c.code.Contains("B") && c.code.Contains("BZ")
```

Comment: But this clause will select strings that contain only `BZ`. For instance in `ABZ` first condition will be true - the string does contain `B` and then the second condition will be true as it also contains `BZ` but the string does not fulfill the requirement of containing `B` and separately `BZ`